# How to get results out of a php script

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine

SOLVED* im trying to create a highscore database for a game im working on

im trying to count the number of users in my database who have a score higher than a given score the query works fine when run through phpmyadmin but im having problems getting results from my php script

the query - `$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`scores`WHERE`score`> '$score'";`

and heres what i have so far

```
 <?php 
        $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'user_pass') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
        mysql_select_db('database') or die('Could not select database');

        // Strings must be escaped to prevent SQL injection attack. 
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'], $db); 
        $score = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['score'], $db); 
        $hash = $_GET['hash']; 


        $secretKey="mysecretkey"; # Change this value to match the value stored in the client javascript below 

        $real_hash = md5($name . $score . $secretKey); 
        if($real_hash == $hash) { 
            // Send variables for the MySQL database class. 
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `scores` WHERE `score` > '$score'";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 

            //echo $row['number'];
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $row['cnt'];
            }
            mysql_result($result, 0);
        } 
?>
```

if it helps im trying to get the result back into unity3d but believe my problem is in the php script, any help would be greatly appreciated

changed to working version incase anybody needs it

Comment: Please, don't use the _deprecated_ `mysql_*` extension for new code, look into `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: what are you getting back, nothing... try echoing out something in the else clause of your hash check to see if that test is passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query with alias

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `scores` WHERE `score` > '$score'";
```

And you have to pass here column alias not the variable name

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $row['cnt'];
}
```

Comment: wow it works! i have literally been at this since all day. thank you i just needed to follow o2kevins advice and remove $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result); and add in your code

Answer (score 1):

Two changes needed:

Firstly use AS in your SQL so you have a column name to use when you print the result.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM `scores` WHERE `score` > '$score'";
```

Secondly change your echo statement to use the column you created in the SQL

```
echo $row['number'];
```

As a side note the mysql_ functions have been deprecated, look into using the [mysqli functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `scores` WHERE `score` > '$score'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result); //what is this for? 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row[$score];//change $score to the field that you want to fetch.
}
```

Comment: not to sure why thats in there tbh, it was just in another script, like i say i have no clue with php :)

Comment: Oh i see. try. Try to comment all or delete all the codes beneath $result and then, try to print_r($result) and post what you get.